# cloudfoundry - vmc non-interactively specifying a "none" url

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I'm looking to non-interactively push an app with a url of "none"

right now my command looks like:

```
vmc push sometestapp -f --framework "standalone" --command "python nowebapp.py" --runtime "python2" --url "none"
```

but this gives me a

```
FAILED
CFoundry::UriNotAllowed: 702: External URIs are not enabled for this account
```

error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you save the manifest, you can edit and use that to re-push the application. Depending on the version of VMC you need to set the URL key to either "none" or just leave it blank.